# How to keep refreshing tokens using refresh token in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, frontend, access-token, refresh-token

I made two servers: a backend and a frontend.

The backend has 5 routes:

- SignIn: which accepts a username and password, and if the user is not registered yet, it will create the account and return an accessToken and a refreshToken.
- Login: that accepts a username and password, and if the credentials are correct, an accessToken and a refreshToken will return.
- Logout: which accepts a refreshToken and removes it from the database ("RefreshTokens").
- Token: which accepts a refreshToken and returns a new accessToken (which only lasts 1 minute).

So far so good, but my problem is the frontend (more specifically in React).
How do I keep the site refreshing the token every 1 minute? What is the most correct way to do this?

Comment: Setup a timer which, when the expiry time of the refresh token nears, send an AJAX call to the server to retrieve a new refresh token.  This is the whole point, to avoid having to explicitly prompt your users to reauthenticate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen gave a good answer to your specific problem. Set up a timer after the user is authenticated. Hit the `Token` route every minute to get the fresh refresh token if that is what you are required.

Answer (score 0):

`token` must be stored in state, and `refresh` and `clear` function must update state

```
 // create tokenInterval 
 const tokenInterval = useRef(0)
 
 //create clearInterval function (for example when user logout)
 const clear = useCallback(() => {
   window.clearInterval(tokenInterval.current)
   tokenInterval.current = 0
 }, [tokenInterval])

 //refresh token every minute if token exist
 useEffect(() => {
   if (token) {
     const interval = 1000 * 60 * 1 // 1min
     if (!tokenInterval.current) {
       refresh()
       tokenInterval.current = window.setInterval(() => {
         refresh()
       }, interval)
  }
     } else {
       clear()
     }
 }, [refresh, token, clear])`
```